# Efficiently reusing color codes in a printf %s substitution in bash

Tags: bash, printf

```
biwhite=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 7)
color_off=$(tput sgr0)

printf "%s$USER%s at %s$HOME%s has path %s$PATH%s" "$biwhite" "$color_off" "$biwhite" "$color_off" "$biwhite" "$color_off"
```

Is there a `printf` shortcut to avoid having to define every `%s` when I want to add color to only certain parts of a statement?

Entering `"$biwhite" "$color_off"` 3 times seems redundant.

Comment: Not an unreasonable thing to ask -- many other languages have a way to refer to a specific positional parameter in their format strings.

Comment: Like `zsh`? *ducks*

Comment: You shouldn't put `$USER`, `$HOME` and `$PATH` in the format string for the same reason as you might not want to just put `$biwhite` and `$color_off` in the format string: if they contain percent signs, you have a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practice to avoid putting parameter expansions in the format string of `printf`, in case they contain percent signs as well. That said, parameter substitution offers a way around some of the repetitiveness.

```
w="${biwhite}X${color_off}"

printf "%s at %s has path %s" "${w/X/$USER}" "${w/X/$HOME}" "${w/X/$PATH}"
```

It's not foolproof, but it's fairly unlikely that `X` will appear in the output of `tput`. You can pick a longer string instead, at the cost of more typing.

I'm afraid, though, that adding color codes to a string is inherently painful.

Comment: Very good answers from everyone! I'm going with @chepner because I think the answer "I'm afraid, though, that adding color codes to a string is inherently painful." is probably the most useful one to know :|

Answer (score 1):

I think you could write a bash function:

```
biwhite=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 7)
color_off=$(tput sgr0)

whiten() {
  echo "$biwhite$1$color_off"
}

echo "$(whiten "$USER") at $(whiten "$HOME") has path $(whiten "$PATH")"
```

Also, why use `printf` if you're not using any of it's formatting capabilities?

Comment: The real question is, rather, why use `echo` instead of `printf`?

Comment: Moreover, you're suggesting OP to replace good code with lots of subshells... that's not really nice.

Comment: Using `printf` over `echo` is directly advised by [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)

Comment: ...`echo`'s behavior is undefined by the standard (and diverges between implementations) under a number of common circumstances, notably including any case where the arguments being passed may include a backslash literal. Notably, the behavior of bash with and without the `xpg_echo` flag enabled (and with and without the `posix` flag in conjunction with `xpg_echo`) is one of these points of divergence.

Answer (score 0):

Provided below is a function which colorizes every other argument, starting with the second. (Thus, a non-colorized prefix can be provided by passing a non-empty string in this first position, or a colorized one by leaving it empty, as here).

Notably, no subshells are involved in this code's execution except in the `tput` invocations used for demonstrative purposes. It is thus, while verbose, very low-overhead to execute.

```
biwhite=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 7)
color_off=$(tput sgr0)

# colorize every other argument, starting from the 2nd.
colorize_words() {
  local start_color end_color
  : "${start_color:=$biwhite}" "${end_color:=$color_off}"
  while (( $# )); do
    printf '%s' "$1"
    shift || break
    printf '%s%s%s' "$start_color" "$1" "$end_color"
    shift || break
  done
  printf '\n'
}

colorize_words "" "$USER" " at " "$HOME" " has path " "$PATH"
```

This can be customized by passing `start_color` and `end_color` values to an individual invocation; for example:

```
# this prints every other argument in red
start_color=$(tput setaf 1) colorize_words "hello " "cruel " world
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Charles. You always have great answers.